# Почему this.$state undefined?

Tags: angularjs, controller

Имеется следующий код, допиленный из генератора angular-fullstack:

```
'use strict';
(function(){

class BookController {
  constructor($state, $scope, BookService) {
    this.BookService = BookService;
    this.$scope = $scope;
    this.$state = $state;
    this.$scope.gotoBook = this.gotoBook;

  }

  $onInit(){
    this.BookService.query((books)=>{
      this.$scope.books = books;
    });
  }

  gotoBook(book){
    console.log(this.$state); // undefined
    this.$state.go('book',{id:book._id});

  }
}

angular.module('bookClubPpUaApp')
  .component('book', {
    templateUrl: 'app/book/main/book.html',
    controller: BookController
  });

})();
```

Мои проблемы начинаются когда я пытаюсь выполнить функцию gotoBook.

Получается следующая ошибка: TypeError: Cannot read property 'go' of undefined.

Хотелось бы знать, что я сделал в этой жизни не так и как это исправить =)
П.С. Компилятор - Babel.

Comment: а кроме этой ошибки есть еще ошибки в консоли? можешь сделать пример на [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) который бы воспроизводил проблему?

Comment: Ошибок кроме означенной нету, сейчас попробую пример создать.

Comment: К сожалению, не нашел как сделать чтобы код компилировался Babel, поэтому печаль. Принимаются любые идеи, даже самые безумные.

Comment: сделай пример с кодом необходимым, чтобы осталось только бабель добавить и скинь ссылку

Comment: Хотя не надо. все ясно

Comment: Если надо, могу проект залить на гит, не проблема.

Comment: добавил ответ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема находится в этой строке:

```
this.$scope.gotoBook = this.gotoBook;
```

после этого присваивания, `this` при вызове `$scope.gotoBook(...)` будет указывать на `$scope`, а не на контроллер. Кроме того все простые вызову функций во view - выполняются в контексте `$scope`. Таким образом при выполнении идет попытка обратиться к `$scope.$state`, которое закономерно пустое.

Решений может быть несколько, начиная от использования [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
this.$scope.gotoBook = this.gotoBook.bind(this);
```

До сохранения `$state` не в контроллере, в `$scope`.

Также, возможным решением может быть использование во view синтаксиса `controller as` и обращения с его помощью напрямую к методам контроллера.

Comment: Можно ссылку на более подробную информацию по последнему способу? Чую, так лучше будет, да и чище.

Comment: @ТимурВалиев, [доки по директиве `ng-controller`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController)